# Angular 5 bookmarkable view selection without routes

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I am working on an Angular 5 application, where we do NOT use routes (we have our own custom menu structure with view selection), but still would like to have bookmarkable URLs, that open a specific view.

Technically this means that the component responsible for the menu and component selection should be able to

- change URL parameters when a menu item is selected and
- select the wanted view when it detects a pre-selected value coming from a bookmarked URL.

I am wondering how this could be achieved. Unfortunately, Angular docs do not give too many pointers once you have a setup slightly different from the standard layout.

Could someone give me a TypeScript sample on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using the Angular's [Location API](https://angular.io/api/common/Location) according to [Ben Nadel's article](https://www.bennadel.com/blog/3331-changing-the-hash-with-the-location-service-in-angular-4-4-0-rc-0.htm).

I have something like the following -- the class `CustomMenuService` is responsible for managing the menu, and it uses the `Location` API to store the selection after the hash, which can be bookmarked.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

import { Location } from '@angular/common';

@Injectable() 
export class CustomMenuService {

  constructor(private location: Location) {
    this.restoreCurrentMenuSelection();   
  }

  private restoreCurrentMenuSelection() {
    const pathWithHash = this.location.path(true);
    if (pathWithHash.indexOf('#') >= 0) {
      const hashPart = fullPathWithHash.split('#', 2)[1];
      // ...
      // parse hashPart and get the wanted view (menu item selection) 
      // ...
    }   
  }  

  public onMenuItemSelected() {
    const selectedMenuItem = // ... encode the selected menu item as string

    this.location.go( encodeURI('#' + selectedMenuItem) );   
  } 
}
```